# How to add kotlin-csv to JetPack Compose project

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I want to add kotlin-csv to my app but I don't know how to do it.

I opened kotlin-csv and I have found that I need to add these lines to build.gradle (Module). I did it

```
implementation 'com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-jvm:1.3.0' 
implementation 'com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0'
```

But I can not run my file. I have an error.

```
import com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.dsl.csvReader
fun main(){
    val csvData: String = "a,b,c\nd,e,f"
    val rows: List<List<String>> = csvReader().readAll(csvData)
    println(rows)
}
```

Output:

FAILURE: Build completed with 5 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

### 5: Task failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAndroidTestAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'jsIrApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsIrRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
          - Variant 'jsLegacyRuntimeElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-js:1.3.0:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-runtime' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
   > Could not resolve com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching variant of com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.1.3', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'metadataApiElements-published' capability com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-metadata:0.15.2:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a usage of 'kotlin-api' of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.1.3')
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
```

I thought that I need to add something else to my app. For example, I have found that I need to add these lines to my app (Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.doyaaaaaken</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-csv-jvm</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.doyaaaaaken</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-csv-js</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have read that I need to add these lines to my pom files but I was not able to find pom.xml file in my project. I use a JetPack Compose.

How can I run this file without errors?

```
import com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.dsl.csvReader
fun main(){
    val csvData: String = "a,b,c\nd,e,f"
    val rows: List<List<String>> = csvReader().readAll(csvData)
    println(rows)
}
```

Comment: Since you tagged this with android-jetpack-compose I assume you are building only an Android (Compose) app. In that case you only need to include the JVM dependency `implementation 'com.github.doyaaaaaken:kotlin-csv-jvm:1.3.0' `

Comment: If I add only jvm version to my build.grade I have a error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mu/KotlinLogging
 at com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.client.CsvFileReader.<init>(CsvFileReader.kt:22)
 at com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.client.CsvReader.open(CsvReader.kt:175)
 at com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.client.CsvReader.readAllWithHeader(CsvReader.kt:57)
 at iPark.animals.plants.TestKt.main(test.kt:7)
 at iPark.animals.plants.TestKt.main(test.kt)

Comment: Thats because the library is using kotlin-logger or SLF4J logger internally and on Android that logger goes nowhere. For me it works also on Android (logging is just a no-op) but it seems you are getting an error on whatever API level / device you are running this. See here for the issue https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv/issues/94. Are you using version 1.3.0?

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 1.3.0 I decide to stop use doyaaaaaken and I use org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser and it's work fine.

Comment: Also krang works very well with csv files. So the main lesson is if something does not work need to find another library.

Comment: Also I understand that I don't need csv file at all because Android has SQL support like ROOM.

Comment: If you have been using the csv file only for data storage then you are correct that there are other options available (including Room). See: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage